# numpy array conversion (split int without having to convert to string)

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy array with numpy.int8 values can I call just the character in the ones value or just the tens value without having to convert that value to a string?

if this is my array:  `x = array([[19, 19, 19],[19, 19, 19],[19, 19, 19]],dtype=int8)`

Is there a way to return just a 1 or 9 without converting it to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert to `str`, You can use integer floor division and divide by 10 to find the number in the 10s place, and use the modulus operator to find the number in the 1s place:

```
>>> x = 19
>>> x % 10
9
>>> x // 10
1
```

Both of these operations are vectorized, and can be applied to your entire array:

```
>>> x = array([[19, 19, 19],[19, 19, 19],[19, 19, 19]],dtype=int8)
>>> x // 10
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)

>>> x % 10
array([[9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9]], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.unravel_index` to get all digits at once:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (12,))
###                 put as many 10s  here  as there are decimal places
###                                  vvvv
>>> digits = np.unravel_index(a, (10, 10, 10))
>>>
>>> a
array([724, 403, 334, 691, 810, 559, 634, 916,  17, 915, 375,  37])
>>> pprint(digits)
(array([7, 4, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6, 9, 0, 9, 3, 0]),
 array([2, 0, 3, 9, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 3]),
 array([4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 9, 4, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7]))
```